# ORA-01779: cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table on updating joined tables

Tags: sql, oracle9i

I have this query.

```
update 
(
select pt.poid_id0, umt.plan_id
from norie.plan_t_test pt 
join norie.UAS_MAPPING_TEST umt on (pt.poid_id0 = umt.plan_id)
)
set plan_id = poid_id0
where poid_id0 <> plan_id;
```

but ORA-01779 displays. Please help.

Comment: show the table schema of relevant tables

Comment: Were you able to get the update to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating a query is always tricky.  Try a merge instead.

```
MERGE INTO uas_mapping_test t1
USING 
(   
  select pt.poid_id0, umt.plan_id
    from norie.plan_t_test pt 
    join norie.UAS_MAPPING_TEST umt on (pt.poid_id0 = umt.plan_id)
) ta ON poid_id0 <> plan_id
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE 
set plan_id = poid_id0
```

Comment: update table1
    set col3 = (select col1 from table2 where key2 = table1.key1)
    where col3 <> (select col1 from table2 where key2 = table1.key1);